# Fix page shift when opening and closing uib-modal of angular ui bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

There is page shift when opening and closing the `uib-modal`. Check https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal . Notice the scrollbar disappearance and appearance.

This question is already asked here ([Opening AngularJS modal causes page to shift if scrollbar exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27995417/opening-angularjs-modal-causes-page-to-shift-if-scrollbar-exists)) but doesn't has a working soultion. The only solution given was to set `overflow-y` to body which creates vertical scrolling even if the scrolling is not needed.

```
body{
overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```

Also visited the following links but couldn't implement it for `uib-modal`. Is there any fix to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

1. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9855
2. https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3714

Answer (score 0):

Shifting may be coming because when modal opens it add some padding to body. Due to some bugs I don't know exactly this padding remains with the body even when modal is closed and because of that page shifts.

When modal is being closed on button click you can try -

```
    $("#ModalId").modal('hide');
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
    $('body').css('padding-right', '');
```

It worked in my case.

Comment: May be this will help -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460369/adding-and-removing-classes-in-angularjs-using-ng-click